# Recursive nested object comparison does not return empty object for similarities

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that compares the changes between 2 objects and returns a result with the difference:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj: Record<string, any>): boolean {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
function extractChanges(
  baseObj: Record<string, any>,
  newObj: Record<string, any>
): Record<string, any> {
  let result: Record<string, any> = {};
   if (
    (isEmptyObject(refObj) && isEmptyObject(newObj)) ||
    (!isEmptyObject(refObj) && isEmptyObject(newObj))
  )
    return result;
  if (!isEmptyObject(newObj) && isEmptyObject(refObj)) return newObj;
  const keys = Object.keys(newObj);
  for (const key of keys) {
    const newValue = newObj[key];
    const baseValue = baseObj[key];
    const isNotScalarType =
      newValue.constructor === Array || newValue.constructor === Object;

    if (isNotScalarType) {
      result = {
        ...result,
        [key]: extractValueChanges(baseObj[key], newObj[key]),
      };
    }
    if (!isNotScalarType && newValue !== baseValue) {
      return {
        ...result,
        [key]: newValue,
      };
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The function works well except that it return an object similar to this one within this example:

```
const obj = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test'
        address: {
          country: 'XXX',
          state: 'XXXX',
          coordinates: {
            longitude: 'xxxx',
            latitude: 'xxxx',
          },
        },
      };

extractChanges(obj) // returns {address: {coordinates:{}}
```

How can I fix the function to return an empty object for nested comparison?

Comment: Hint: Your for loop would’ve been better written as a reduce

Comment: Also, I hope this is academic or personal, if it’s for real world usage, use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff)

Comment: Are you sure this is what the function returns?
I tested it, and it returned an empty object.

Comment: @user11060338 question updated.